# Vector initializer list passed as a function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization

I have a function that receives an `std::vector<int>` as such:

```
void foo(std::vector<int>);
```

And I would like to repeatedly call `foo()` with small vectors generated on the fly. I was trying to create a new vector on the fly using an initializer list but it seems to allocate a vector of size *n*, instead of initializing it.

For example:

```
foo(std::vector<int> { 1});
foo(std::vector<int> { 4});
foo(std::vector<int> { 5});
```

It seems to create 3 vectors, allocated for 1, 4 and 5 default (0) elements respectively.

Instead I would like to create 3 vectors of size 1, but with value 1, 4 and 5. I am aware I could use the constructor (n, value) like `vector<int>` (1,1), (1,4) and (1,5), but for my understanding I would like to understand why my initializer list is not doing what I expect it to.

Comment: That should be working. Even `foo({1});` etc. is fine.

Comment: I get the behavior that you are expecting. I tested it on Linux using g++ 4.7.3. What platform are you using?

Comment: I am using embedded Android with clang 3.1. I am building for Android 4.2.2, arm 32 bits.

Comment: I managed to get it work, I had to redefine the vector constructor that takes the initializer list, something funky was being done elsewhere, it's fixed now, thanks!

Comment: What funky thing was being done where? Was the problem within Clang or its standard library? Please provide an answer to your own question and maybe edit the question accordingly too.

Comment: @user3277261 if there is a bug in the std::vector implementation you are using, consider reporting bug instead of just fixing it (e.g. if you upgrade compiler later and forget about this but they did not fix it, the error may magically reappear)

Answer (score 9):

Declaration `std::vector<int> { 1}` creates 1 element with value as 1. Element created will have value 1 at 0th position.

Declaration `std::vector<int> (1,6)` creates 1 element with value as 6. Element created will have value 6 at 0th position.

The declaration provided in question work fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


void foo(std::vector<int> vec)
{
    std::cout<<"size of vec "<<vec.size()<<std::endl;

    for(int x =0; x < vec.size(); ++x)
    {
        std::cout<<vec[x]<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(std::vector<int> { 1});
    foo(std::vector<int> { 4});
    foo(std::vector<int> { 5});
    foo(std::vector<int> (1,6));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "allocates 1 element with value as 2" even mean?

Comment: @juanchopanza I think it means `capacity() == 2`.

Comment: @Constructor I seriously doubt that!

Comment: @juanchopanza This is just my guess. :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for pointing out the mistake, that was just a typing error.

Comment: @Nik Why does `std::vector<int> (1,6)` work without an identifier? Is it a way to create a temporary unnamed vector?

Comment: @Ziu it works because we are invoking constructor provided in std::vector